# in rails, access controller variable/params in view/javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller

I have in controller:

```
def add_nested_slot
  @slot_name = params[:name] 
   respond_to do |format|
   format.js {}
  end
end
```

I would like to access @slot_name in my file.js.erb.
How shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Suposing the `add_nested_slot` method is a controller action, this variable is available at the `add_nested_slot.js.erb` view file.

You can access it like this:

```
console.log('This is the slot name: ' + <%= @slot_name %>);
```

Comment: thank you, it still doesn't work.
Can I write in view:

var slotname = <%= @slot_name%>

?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this. Have you checked if `@slot_name` is not empty?